# Unable to upload a Excel file using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, io, httpurlconnection, xls

I am **successfully** using the HttpURLConnection to upload ***.txt files**. Now I have the task to change the program for uploading every filetype. I **tried** my program with **.xls files**. The files are placed on the server, but the content isn't readable.

Like you see here:

> ÃÃÃ Â¡Â±Ã¡>Ã¾Ã¿
>   Å’Â¸Ã¤ÃŒÃŒÃŒS
>   Sheet1Sheet2Sheet3Worksheets4 $â‚¬,Ã¾Ã¿3Ã â€¦Å¸Ã²Ã¹OhÂ«â€˜+'Â³Ã™0Å“8Å’@`xâ€žÃ¤Microsoft CorporationMicrosoft Excel@â€Ã¸(ÂºÂ»Ã¾Ã¿3Ã â€¦Å¸Ã²Ã¹OhÂ«â€˜+'Â³Ã™0Ëœ8Å’@`xâ€žÃ¤Microsoft CorporationMicrosoft Excel@â€Ã¸(ÂºÂ»@â€Ã¸(ÂºÂ»ÃŒï¿½Ã¡Â°ÃÃ¢\pMicrosoft Corporation

Here my code snippet:

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(testdocumentURL).openConnection(); 
    urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("X-Method-Override", "PUT");     
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml"); 
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ Client.getPassword());
    urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
    urlConn.setDoInput(true);
    urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConn.setFollowRedirects(false);
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Slug", "Connectiontest/test.xls"); 
    String write = readFile(test.xls);
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length","" + write.length());
    urlConn.getOutputStream().write(write.getBytes("UTF8"));
```

In my optinion there are 2 ways to solve this problem.

1. change the **output** at .write(write.getBytes("UTF8"))
2. change the **intput**

At the moment I read the files like this:

```
    readFile(String test){
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(test));
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
        stringBuilder.append(ls);
    }
    reader.close();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

I tried to change the RequestProperty() in this ways:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
```

or

```
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Do somebody know to Upload a .xls file like this? I have to **prefere** the HttpURLConnector, my boss said. :/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't treat the Excel file as a `String`.  Change `readFile` to read the file into a `byte[]` instead, then write that to the connection output stream.

Comment: Hi David Grant, thx for this helpful advise. Now I use a FileInputStream in my `readFile()` and I'm able to upload every filetype I want.

Comment: Thanks bud, Saved my day. This was my exact situatuion.

Answer (score 0):

Set the content type as application/vnd.ms-excel and then give it a try

Comment: Hi Chris, I already tried different content-types. non worked :(